# Convert IHTMLDOMNode to IHTMLElement?

Tags: c#, html, dom, casting

I would like to convert an `IHTMLDOMNode` to `IHTMLElement` in C#, I have tried the following:

```
IHTMLElement tempElement = node as IHTMLElement;
//node is a instance of IHTMLDOMNode internface
```

However, this did not work -- `tempElement` is `null`. Is there a way to perform this conversion correctly? Note that in my application, I try to use `WebBrowser` to access every node in the DOM tree and get their coordinates.

here are my source code, could you tell me what should I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;

namespace TestWindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.bing.com");
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            IHTMLDOMNode bodyNode = (IHTMLDOMNode)webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement;
            TranversalDOM(document, bodyNode);
        }

        private void TranversalDOM(HTMLDocument document, IHTMLDOMNode node)
        {
            if (node.nodeType == 3)
            {
                string nodeInfo = node.nodeValue.ToString();

                nodeInfo += ">>>";
                IHTMLElement tempElement = node as IHTMLElement;
                //how to convert IHTMLDOMNode to IHTMLElement?

                int X1 = findPosX(tempElement);
                int X2 = X1 + tempElement.offsetWidth;
                int Y1 = findPosY(tempElement);
                int Y2 = Y1 + tempElement.offsetHeight;
                nodeInfo += " LeftTop: (";
                nodeInfo += X1.ToString();
                nodeInfo += ",";
                nodeInfo += Y1.ToString();
                nodeInfo += ")";
                nodeInfo += " RightBottom: (";
                nodeInfo += X2.ToString();
                nodeInfo += ",";
                nodeInfo += Y2.ToString();
                nodeInfo += ")";
                listBox1.Items.Add(nodeInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection childNodes = node.childNodes as IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection;
                foreach (IHTMLDOMNode n in childNodes)
                {
                    TranversalDOM(document, n);
                }
            }
        }


        public int findPosX(IHTMLElement obj)
        {
            int curleft = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent != null)
            {
                while (obj.offsetParent != null)
                {
                    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                    obj = obj.offsetParent;
                }
            }

            return curleft;
        }

        public int findPosY(IHTMLElement obj)
        {
            int curtop = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent != null)
            {
                while (obj.offsetParent != null)
                {
                    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                    obj = obj.offsetParent;
                }
            }

            return curtop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert when it is not an `IHTMLElement`.

Comment: I have posted my source code, could you tell me what should I do?

Comment: This is recursive so it could happen when node is deep. put a breakpoint on when value is null and see what is the type. I suspect it is a comment.

Comment: Thx, u r correct.
when the node is a Text node, it can not canvert to IHTMLElement

Answer (score -3):

I am not familiar with these interfaces but you might try:

```
IHTMLElement tempElement = (IHTMLElement)node;
```